# \autoref calls definition theorem siam latex template

Tags: hyperref, theorems, ref, journal

My \autoref is calling my definition theorem. How do I fix this that is get it to refer to definition as definition?
I would prefer to not change the numbering of definitions and theorems in my document.

```
% SIAM Article Template
\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart190516}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{color}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
  \newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

    \renewcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{1}
asfd
\end{definition}

\autoref{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\cref` instead.

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[review,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamart190516}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{definition}\label{1}
        asfd
    \end{definition}

hyperref autoref    \autoref{1}

cleverref cref  \cref{1}    
        
\end{document}
```